# How to change resolution of CentOS 6.5 Resolution on virtualbox (Host: Win7)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, resolution, xorg

So I'm trying to configure the resolution of my CentOS 6.5 virtualbox. Here are the steps I have taken:

Installed guest additions
Changed virtualbox preferences > Display > Maximum Guest Screen Size: Hint (Width 1920, height 1080)
Restarted VirtualBox
System > Preferences > Display only shows 1024x768 and lower as possible resolutions.

I had also tried editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf to include the following:

`Section "Screen"
  Depth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
  EndSubSection
EndSection`

However changing this caused box to crash to a black window with "CentOS 6.5" printed. It would let me type but would not let me run commands; hitting enter returned a newline but no actions. There was no prompt.

I've also seen instructions to run a command changing the MaxGuestOSResolution (or something) in my host terminal, but I'm hosting on windows so that isn't an option.

Is there something I'm overlooking? I've done a lot of google searching but nothing has given me the option to increase the resolution. I've also taken a couple steps that I didn't list here, but I can't remember them all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Virtualbox guest additions installed too? There's a graphics driver attached to that.

Comment: @NathanC how do I manipulate that driver? I haven't seen any settings that would help me but I might be looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Once you install the actual extensions (using the menu) and reboot the VM, they'll automatically be enabled. Also make sure you're allocating enough video memory to the VM for a high resolution (I normally max it out unless it's a server).

Comment: @NathanC I have allocated 128mb for the vm video memory, which is the max vbox allowed. And I have rebooted the VM since installing vbox guest additions, but like I said it did not give me any more options for resolution. Is there somewhere for me to check the driver settings? I'm unfamiliar with CentOS.

Comment: [It sounds like you may be out of luck](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=55626) ...CentOS 6.x doesn't like the drivers that come with virtualbox it seems.

Comment: @NathanC if I used a different VM, such as VMWare player, would that potentially help?

Comment: Maybe. Fedora is the desktop-friendly version of Redhat if you like that range of distros.

Comment: I've faced this exact issue before and I bookmarked the site(s) which helped me out but unfortunately that's on my home PC so if no one else answers then I can get those to you in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worked found a solution to this problem. It would be hard to pinpoint all the environment settings changed since I first got the VM, but hopefully this will be enough:

1. Have guest additions installed (for either Virtualbox or VMware, whatever you're using).
2. DELETE the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf (or to be safer, `mv` it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.unused or something)

This opened up a huge range of resolutions for me, and among them 1920 x 1080. Hopefully this helps other people too.

Comment: Doesn't work with CentOS 7

Answer (score 1):

More steps to add 1920x1080 Screen resolution.
Just make sure that you "reboot" after you uncomment X11's xorg.conf file before you run the automated scripts further down below.

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.unused
```

You can use the following scripts. Also credit to Adam Prax's Answer
[How to change resolution of CentOS 6.5 Resolution on virtualbox (Host: Win7)](https://superuser.com/questions/750382/how-to-change-resolution-of-centos-6-5-resolution-on-virtualbox-host-win7)

```
#!/bin/bash
Diplay_Name=`xrandr | grep connected | cut -d' ' -f1`
Display_Spec=`cvt 1920 1080 | grep Modeline | cut -d' ' -f2 |cut -d '"' -f2`
Display_Params=`cvt 1920 1080 | grep Modeline | cut -d' ' -f2-18`
xrandr --newmode $Display_Params
xrandr --addmode $Diplay_Name $Display_Spec
xrandr --output $Diplay_Name --mode $Display_Spec
```

You should have something commands execution like below.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1920x1080_60.00 
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

Then, you can use VirtualBox’s “View -> Auto-resize Guest Display” to let VirtualBox automatic resize work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For me (CentOS 7 on VirtualBox 4.3.10 with Guest Additions 4.3.18), the answer provided by Ray Sheu nearly worked.

I only had to change the definition of Display_Params to also remove the double quotes around the mode name:

```
Display_Params=`cvt 1920 1080 | grep Modeline | cut -d' ' -f2-18 | sed s/'"'//g`
```

I also had set the screen size hint of 1920x1080 as described in the answer by Devon Parsons, but that alone did not help. I did not check out whether that was necessary at all.